# Why Code UI does not capture Remote Desktop (mstsc) steps?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to automate few things with Visual Studio **Coded UI**. Now for some windows like **Calc** it captures steps pretty well. But for **mstsc** it doesn't record or recognize a single step.

Please see if following image helps to clarify my point.

[image]

Comment: If you look at [Supported Configurations and Platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx) I think it's only be chance that Calculator works (check out the platforms list - Win32 applications are listed as "May work with some known issues, but not officially supported.")

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to do. Your question is very vague. Please read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @AdrianHHH Question is pretty simple, Coded UI is working with Calc and not with mstsc. What else do you want?

Comment: Just saying "it does not work" tells us nothing. Describe the steps you have tried in a way that would allow someone else to repeat what you have tried. Please read [mcve]. Since I do not have mstc I cannot try it, hence I am trying to help you to help yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Coded UI works by interacting with the many UI controls that together form the windows and the desktop. Programs like the Remote Desktop Connection appear to work by creating a window that has a picture (perhaps a video) of the remote desktop. It does not have the actual UI controls. Hence Coded UI only sees one UI control, the control that contains the picture of the remote desktop.

To do Coded UI testing on a remote desktop requires that the Coded UI test runs on that remote computer. That means that the Coded UI tests and the application (or at least the UI part of the application) run on the same computer.

Comment: I am not using remote computer.. I am using mstsc of my own computer. Secondly, there is tool with Visual Studio toolkit, 'Spy++' that detects controls of Remote Desktop window.

Comment: @PranitKothari (1) Your question has a screenshot of "Remote Desktop Connection" so it appears that you are using a remote computer. (2) I do not know mstsc but a quick web search suggests that it provides terminal services on to remote computers. (3) If other programs (such as Spy) can see into the remote window then you missed significant information from your question. (4) If you are asking about the "Currently recording" on the "calc" window then but not on the other then, again, you missed significant information from your question; I have found that that message is often omitted.

Comment: @ AdrianHHH Actually I want to automate few steps of mstsc, and I don't want to do anything on remote machine.